# Is there a way to quickly create a style from a set of selected attributes?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, code-generation, styles

I currently want to create a wpf style by selecting a group of attributes, e.g. `Height`, `Width` of a button, then right click and call a command like *"Generate style from selection"* and the IDE will do the rest for me: add .Resource tags, and a Style with sample `x:Key` and put the attributes' names and values into `Setter` tags.

Is it possible? Any addons are welcome. I prefer to have a free solution. Please discuss!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Expression Blend at your disposal, creating a new style is fairly simple.  Just a matter of stubbing out the style in code

```
<Style x:Name="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"/>
```

Open the Resource browser, select the style you just made, and then use the properties box to set the properties.

As for Visual Studio, I have not yet seen a WPF extension that would do it even this automated.  The XAML designer in Visual Studio leaves a lot to be desired for me, and one of the reasons is the style creation.

Blend has style visualization, VS2010 does not.  Any styling stuff that I do, is in Blend.